# Set Page Size in Units with NReco (WkHtmlToPdf)

Tags: html, asp.net, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

Is there a way to set print page size in millimeters, like you can with borders, in NReco - the html to pdf wrapper for wkhtmltopdf? Found a way to specify one of four page sizes in the [docs](http://www.nrecosite.com/doc/NReco.PdfGenerator/html/T_NReco_PdfGenerator_PageSize.htm), which isn't precise enough.

From reading the [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt) docs themselves, it seems like it's also limited to predefined page sizes, rather than setting them manually in units of length.

Making this question in case I am, hopefully, wrong. Need to set page to something 15x10cm for example.

Edit: I am having trouble forcing the library to use the html page settings (as an alternative to not setting anything in the html, and setting height/width/margins in NReco, as shown in my partial answer below). This:

```
    @page {
       size: 4in 3in;
       margin: 0mm 0mm 0mm 0mm;
    }
```

actually works on print, but when I try to force NReco to use it with:

```
pdfConverter.CustomWkHtmlArgs = "--print-media-type";
```

it does nothing. Example is from front page of NReco's site too, which makes it funnier.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at this snippet from the wkhtmltopdf documentation:

```
      --page-height <unitreal>        Page height
  -s, --page-size <Size>              Set paper size to: A4, Letter, etc.
                                      (default A4)
      --page-width <unitreal>         Page width
```

I would say that using --page-height and --page-width would do the trick. Logic would say that these will set the page height and width in points, but in fact it is mm. If you need to convert, there are 25.4 mm in an inch, and 72 points in an inch.

Comment: I am using the NReco wrapper. The wrapper sets the page size in mm or to a default "A4" size like you showed above. I upvoted your answer because I am sure it works in wkhtml itself, but I am still having trouble rendering things correctly (see my answer), so I am leaving this open for now.

Answer (score 2):

Quick answer to your question is yes, the settings are in `mm` when you use the `height` and `width` properties, so what you are doing is correct with regard to the C# code, your sizing issue is the converter employing a 'smart' resizing technique, which is on by default. The ratio being correct but the dimensions reduced is exactly the same issue I had, which was resolved by the `--disable-smart-shrinking` option being included.

For a fuller picture:
I've just finished step one of getting prescription printing direct from a new Razor app done, the PDFs being generated via the NReco wrapper. I have to print to a fixed prescription sheet (215mm x 176mm) with a small margin around it. This is the code that I've got in the Controller, which returns the pdf as the *fileResult* variable.

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> OutputScript(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        var model = await GetViewModelForScript(id.Value);
        if (model == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        // create a string writer to receive the HTML code
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();

        // get the view to render
        ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(ControllerContext, "Script", null);
        // create a context to render a view based on a model
        ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(
                ControllerContext,
                viewResult.View,
                new ViewDataDictionary(model),
                new TempDataDictionary(),
                stringWriter
                );

        // render the view to a HTML code
        viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, stringWriter);

        // return the HTML code
        string htmlToConvert = stringWriter.ToString();

        // instantiate the HTML to PDF converter
        HtmlToPdfConverter htmlToPdfConverter = new HtmlToPdfConverter();
        htmlToPdfConverter.CustomWkHtmlArgs = "  --print-media-type --title \"SMS Script " + model.ScriptID + "\" --dpi 300 --disable-smart-shrinking";
        htmlToPdfConverter.PageHeight = 215;
        htmlToPdfConverter.PageWidth = 176;
        var margins = new PageMargins();
        margins.Bottom = 4;
        margins.Top = 4;
        margins.Left = 5;
        margins.Right = 5;
        htmlToPdfConverter.Margins = margins;
        htmlToPdfConverter.Orientation = PageOrientation.Landscape;
        // render the HTML code as PDF in memory
        byte[] pdfBuffer = htmlToPdfConverter.GeneratePdf(htmlToConvert);

        // send the PDF file to browser
        FileResult fileResult = new FileContentResult(pdfBuffer, "application/pdf");
        fileResult.FileDownloadName = "Script.pdf";

        return fileResult;

    }
```

The way it is now all the`@media print` directives are obeyed, hiding the labels that show on the screen "preview" when the PDF is generated for printing.

Comment: I "solved" the problem by setting zoom settings instead of disabling smart shrinking: converter.Zoom = 2; two just being 2x here. I had to configure zoom settings for the amazon server, the azure server, and local machines separately, because apparently its based on the machines built in graphics system (don't ask). I also wrote my own helper to put comments in the html that the PDF converter can see. If that's something you would find helpful, let me know.    With everything you and I tried, I still can't get extremely small margins to print right without hacks.

Answer (score 1):

Note: I will be editing this answer if I get somewhere, but for now, I guess something is better than nothing for whoever might read this.

Posting an answer that others might find helpful but that isn't the full solution to my problem:

```
HtmlToPdfConverter pdfConverter = new HtmlToPdfConverter();

//The page width and page height values are in mm
pdfConverter.PageWidth = 102;
pdfConverter.PageHeight = 77;
```

This should NOT be the accepted answer - for some reason it does NOT fully match simple html sizing. For example, if I create an html document with size ratios of 4x3 and then set these props appropriately, the resulting image on the page still does not take up the entire page (ends up smaller).

If I run the following html and set page sizes to 102 mm x 72mm I get the screenshot below, which is way off despite having the ratios right:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .reportBody {
            padding: 0px;
            border: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
        }

        .reportTable{
            padding: 0px;
            border: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
            width: 102mm; 
            height: 77mm; 
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body class = "reportBody">
    <table class = "reportTable">
        <tr>
            <td style = "background-color:red">
                Row 1 Column 1
            </td>
            <td style = "background-color:blue">
                Row 1 Column 2
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style = "background-color:green">
                Row 2 Column 1
            </td>
            <td style = "background-color:yellow">
                Row 2 Column 2
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table> 
</body>

</html>
```

[image]